# Best (free?) decompiler for C# with Visual Studio integration?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, decompiling

In my Java development I have had great benefit from the [Jad/JadClipse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAD_%28JAva_Decompiler%29) decompiler. It made it possible to *know* why a third-party library failed rather than the usual guesswork.

I am looking for a similar setup for C# and Visual Studio. That is, a setup where I can point to any class or variable in my code and get a code view for that particular class.

What is the best setup for this? I want to be able to use the usual "jump to declaration/implementation" that I use to navigate my own code. It doesn't *have* to be free, but it would be a bonus if it was.

It should support Visual Studio 2008 or Visual Studio 2005 and .NET 2 and 3(.5).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is a good article about [Reflector and how to integrate Reflector into Visual Studio](http://en.csharp-online.net/Visual_Studio_Hacks%E2%80%94Hack_64:_Examine_the_Innards_of_Assemblies).

> Of particular interest is the Reflector.VisualStudio Add-In. This
>   add-in, created by Jaime Cansdale, allows for Reflector to be hosted
>   within Visual Studio. With this add-in, you can have Reflector
>   integrated within the Visual Studio environment.
>  To get
>   started, you will need to have the latest version of Reflector on your
>   machine. Once you have downloaded Reflector, download the latest
>   version of the Reflector.VisualStudio Add-In from
>   http://www.testdriven.NET/reflector. The download contains a number of
>   files that need to be placed in the same directory as Reflector.exe.
>   To install the add-in, drop to the command line and run:
>
> ```
> Reflector.VisualStudio.exe /install
> ```
>
> After the add-in has been installed, you can start using Reflector from Visual Studio. You’ll notice a new menu item, Addins, which has a
>   menu option titled Reflector. This option, when selected, displays the
>   Reflector window, which can be docked in the IDE. Additionally, the
>   add-in provides context menu support.
>  When you right-click
>   in an open code file in Visual Studio, you’ll see a Reflector menu
>   item that expands into a submenu with options to disassemble the code
>   into C# or Visual Basic, display the call graph or callee graph, and
>   other related choices. The context menu also includes a Synchronize
>   with Reflector menu item that, when clicked, syncs the object browser
>   tree in the Reflector window with the current code file.

Comment: This is no longer free as of March 10, 2011.

Answer (score 10):

Try the open-source software http://ilspy.net/

Answer (score 4):

The [Scout plugin](http://code.google.com/p/scoutplugin/) integrates Reflector with ReSharper, if you happen to use that tool.

Answer (score 3):

ReSharper 6 (currently [available for early access](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/ReSharper/ReSharper+6.0+Nightly+Builds)) supports decompiling in Visual Studio, with the entire ReSharper's navigation feature pack applicable to decompiled code. We have [blogged about this](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2011/02/resharper-6-bundles-decompiler-free-standalone-tool-to-follow/) some time ago.

Answer (score 2):

I think [dotPeek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) is best **free** Tools For **Decompile C#**  code and **.Net** assembly

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it can integrate with Visual Studio, but [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) can disassemble .NET assemblies into a number of .NET languages, or show the IL.

Answer (score 1):

Remotesoft's **[Salamander .NET decompiler](http://www.remotesoft.com/salamander/index.html)** doesn't integrate in Visual Studio, but it can **generate Visual Studio .NET project files** for easy recompilation. It's not free.

Answer (score 1):

You can attach .NET Reflector to Visual Studio by simply using "Open with" on the DLL/EXE in the `bin` folder, and choosing Reflector (and set as default). Also, many tools (such as [TestDriven.NET](http://www.testdriven.net/) if I recall, and possibly ReSharper) provide a level of .NET Reflector integration.