# Is it possible to decompile a SQL Server CLR stored procedure assembly?

Tags: .net, sql-server, decompiling, sqlclr

We've got a few internal proprietary database CLR stored procs (MSSQL 2005) that were put together by a former employee who misplaced (and never checked in) the .NET source code used to build the assemblies.  These were not obfuscated.

Is it possible to reverse-engineer the assemblies to a state where we could edit the source and recompile?

Comment: Have you tried using Reflector on it?  It's usually pretty good at decompiling.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, as long as you have the assembly and it hasn't been obtusified in any way.

.NET Reflector should work for you:

http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/

Comment: "Obtusified?"  I didn't know Sarah Palin was on SO!  +1

Comment: You betcha! Actually, I never found a the correct usage for that word. :P

Comment: Thanks much for that, however I do have a problem.  I'd extracted the DLL from the server using the method found here: http://serverfault.com/questions/139703/extracting-a-sqlclr-assembly - however, when I open in Reflector, it says "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."  It opened any other .NET assembly I'd compiled just fine.  Any ideas?

Comment: Is there any other stack trace info after the message?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of suggestions here:

[Best (free?) decompiler for C# with Visual Studio integration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/214764/best-free-decompiler-for-c-with-vs-integration)

Don't forget that you can also use SQL Server profiler to trap the SQL statements.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the Assembly extracted into a DLL, you can use the open-source [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/) to decompile it. You won't be able to see all of the compiler options used when compiling it, nor will you be able to see how the source code was broken out into separate files. Still, you will see enough to be able to create a Visual Studio project, create the `Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs` file, add the references, etc. so that you can properly add it so source control and then start editing it.